# Recorded Actions can't be run in TestAgent

Tags: .net, coded-ui-tests

Using CodedUI Test(VS 2012) I have recorded some actions and generated a .dll . Now I am attempting to Playback the same in another machine where only Test Agent is installed. The first Action i.e Launching Browser works fine. But the remaining actions are not running . I hope the problem is with UIMap controls that are unable to find in the TestAgent installed machine. I have cross checked all the DLL files in the installed path. Almost all required file are there. Did I miss something?

Comment: Is your test agent running interactively? And is the windows session of the remote machine logged on?

Comment: Yes interactive only. Remote machine means you are mentioning the machine which has Test Agent , Right? If so, Yes that also Logged on.